# Dataflow pipeline waits for elements from all streams before performing GroupBy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

We are running a Dataflow job that handles multiple input streams. Some of them are high traffic and some of them rarely get messages through. We are joining all streams with a "shared" stream that contains information relevant to all elements. This is a simplified example of the pipeline:

[image: Pipeline Example]

I noticed that the job will not produce any output, until *both* streams contain some traffic.

For example, let's suppose that `Stream 1` gets a steady flow of traffic, whereas `Stream 2` does not produce any messages for a period of time. For this time, the job's DAG will show elements being accumulated in the `GroupByKey` step but nothing will be propagated beyond it. I can also see the Flatten PCollections step showing input elements for the left side of the graph but not the right one. This creates a problem when dealing with high traffic *and* low traffic streams in the same job, since it will cause output to be delayed for as much as it takes for `Stream 2` to pick up messages.

I am not sure if the observation is correct, but I wanted to ask if this is how Flatten/GroupByKey works in general and if so, if the issue we're seeing can be avoided through an alternative way of constructing the pipeline.

(Example JobID: 2017-02-10_06_48_01-14191266875301315728)

Comment: what kind of windows and triggering are you using in that step? You should be able to configure your windows/triggers to work even with no elements from a stream.

Comment: @Pablo `FixedWindows` and `Sessions` with default triggers and a 30 minute gap duration for the second case. 

As far as I know, I could add a trigger that uses processing time or number of elements added to fire prematurely, but I would like to avoid that since it would mean that some of the sessions would be incomplete (30 minutes of inactivity might not have passed) when the pane is fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the documentation of [group-by-key](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key#groupbykey-with-windowing) the default behavior is to wait for all data within the window to have arrived -- this is necessary to ensure correctness of down-stream results.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may be able to use [triggers](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/triggers) to cause the aggregates to be output earlier.

You may also be able to use the slow-stream as a [side-input](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key#joins-with-pardo-and-side-inputs) to the processing of the fast-stream.

If you're still stuck, it would help if you could describe in more detail the contents of the streams and how you're trying to use them, since more detailed answers depend on the goal.

Comment: Does this mean that if one of the streams doesn't produce any amount of elements the `GroupByKey` will wait until there's at least one element for each of the streams for it to know it needs to close a `Session`? The exact use case is that I'm trying to implement a user session, where I am keeping track of user activity across a plethora of message types (clicks, page views etc.). Some sessions might have elements for all streams (e.g. a user clicked something _and_ viewed a page), but some might not.

Comment: The job is consuming ~20 different streams right now, with a subset of them being eligible for being "slow" or not propagating elements at all. I think using side-inputs might not be the way to go since it might be any one of those streams that fails to deliver or is slow.


I am also thinking about the case of a misconfiguration: let's say that for some reason one of my subscription fails to deliver messages because of a configuration error or maybe messages not being propagated to it any more. Does this mean that the pipeline would hold on to session windows indefinitely?

Comment: The actual behavior depends on how the up-stream sources track the watermark. For example, if there is no data arriving the PubSub source will allow the watermark to advance to the current time. But, the CoGroupByKey step will need to wait until the watermark of all upstream sources have advanced past the end of the fixed windows, etc.